# Show that $\sup\ A < \sup\ B \implies \exists b\in B \ |\ b \ \text{is upper bound for} A$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, supremum-and-infimum

Show that $\sup\ A < \sup\ B \implies \exists b\in B \ |\ b \  \text{is upper bound for} A$

Let $\gamma = \sup\ B - \sup\ A > 0$ and $\epsilon = \frac{\gamma}{2}> 0$ further set $b=\sup\ B- \epsilon$, this should force $b\in B$. At the same time we have $b=\sup\ B- \epsilon=\sup\ A + \gamma-\epsilon=\sup\ A + \frac{\gamma}{2}$. So $b$ is an upper bound of $A$.

Is this line of reasoning valid or am I missing something?

P.S this is exercise 1.3.9 in Understanding Analysis by Abbott.

Comment: You can't assume $(\sup B - \epsilon)$ is an element of $B$.  Instead, all you can show is that there's some $b \in B$ such that $b \geq \sup B - \epsilon$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't assume $\sup B-\epsilon$ is in $B$ as Brian pointed out. Consider for example $B=\{3\}$ and $A=\{2\}$. Then $\gamma=1$ and $\sup B-\epsilon=2.5\not\in B$.

Instead we can argue that $\sup A$ is strictly less than the least upper bound of $B$, so by definition it cannot be an upper bound of $B$, so there is some $b\in B$ with $b>\sup A\geq a$ for all $a\in A$, thus $b$ is an upper bound for $A$.